# Implement Tree with checkboxes and drag drop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im trying to implement Tree view in Vue with checkboxes and also with drag & drop. But I do not know where to start.

I implemented checkboxes but I do not know how to add support when parent is selected to select all children, and also when select all children to select parent ?

Also Im having issue with Drag and Drop, I tried ussing vue-draggable but I do not know how to implement it

Im trying to implement, something like this:

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/treeview/check-box/

Here is my sandbox, what I have managed to implement:

https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-cookies-8lxxf

Answer (score 3):

I had a go at doing this with Vue using a [recursive component](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/10/23/vue-js-tree-menu-recursive-components/) which can be found below. It shows how you can select all the children from the parent and how you could use vue-draggable (though you can only drag on the same tier). It should be a decent starting point, it needs a few tweaks.

EDIT:

To accommodate for drag and drop on multiple levels, I've edited the code so that the draggables are in the same group. I've tested it quickly and the concept works but it still needs some tweaks. Support for nested vue-draggable can be found [here](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/82), I also made a fork of the JSFiddle on GitHub that works so you can [see how they implemented nesting](https://jsfiddle.net/nkazvets/)

```js
let tree = {
  draggableOptions: {group: 'share'},
  label: 'root',
  selected: false,
  nodes: [
    {
      label: 'item1',
      selected: false,
      nodes: [
        {
          label: 'item1.1',
          selected: false
        },
        {
          label: 'item1.2',
          selected: false,
          nodes: [
            {
              label: 'item1.2.1',
              selected: false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      label: 'item2',
      selected: false
    }
  ]
}

Vue.component('tree-menu', { 
  template: '#tree-menu',
  props: [ 'nodes', 'label', 'depth', 'selected' ],
  data() {
     return {
       showChildren: false
     }
  },
  computed: {
    iconClasses() {
      return {
        'fa-plus-square-o': !this.showChildren,
        'fa-minus-square-o': this.showChildren
      }
    },
    labelClasses() {
      return { 'has-children': this.nodes }
    },
    indent() {
      return { transform: `translate(${this.depth * 50}px)` }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChildren() {
       this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
    
    },
    tickChildren(ev) {
      this.selected = !this.selected;  
      this.tickRecursive(this);
    },
    tickRecursive(node) {
       if(node.nodes && node.nodes.length)
          node.nodes.forEach(x => {
            x.selected = this.selected;
            this.tickRecursive(x);
          });
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tree
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tree-menu {
  .label-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    .has-children {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.7.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.16.0/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h4>Implement Tree with checkboxes and drag drop<br/><small>(Using Vue, Recursive Component, Vue Draggable)</small><br /><small><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260675/implement-tree-with-checkboxes-and-drag-drop" target="_blank">For StackOverflow Question</a></small></h4>
  <div id="app">
   
  <tree-menu 
             :nodes="tree.nodes" 
             :depth="0"   
             :label="tree.label"
             :selected="tree.selected"
             ></tree-menu>
       
 
  </div>
    
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="tree-menu">

  <div class="tree-menu">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      <div :style="indent" :class="labelClasses" @click.stop="toggleChildren">
        <i v-if="nodes" class="fa" :class="iconClasses"></i>
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="selected" @input="tickChildren" @click.stop />
        {{label}}
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <draggable v-model="nodes" :options="{group:{ name:'g1'}}">    
    <tree-menu 
      v-if="showChildren"
      v-for="node in nodes" 
      :nodes="node.nodes" 
      :label="node.label"
      :depth="depth + 1"
      :selected="node.selected"
      :key="node"
    >
    </tree-menu>
            </draggable>

  </div>

</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Shoejep it looks ok, can you please tell how could I implement drag & drop since now it is not working in your code

Comment: @Loki It works for items on the same tier, I'm guessing you want drag and drop from different tiers?

Comment: Yes I would like to drag and drop from different levels

Comment: @Loki I've updated my answer to show how it can be done, needs some more work

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. They have implemented everything you need to start with. https://vuejsexamples.com/tree-and-multi-select-component-based-on-vue-js-2/

Comment: I allready looked at it, I was thinking more like a simple jsfiddle as example where I can see how it is working

Comment: here's a code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/halower/vue-tree/tree/master/demo

Comment: No dude, i do not need library, I want simple code that demonstrates how it can be solved